# How to read changes from SVN repo

Tags: svn, facebook

I'm trying to do some sort of strange Facebook App which notifies developers of changes on the SVN such as new branches and versions, however to achieve this I need to ask SVN what changes have been made and the comments of those changes,version,etc.. However all the call I found for SVN on tigris.org talk about how do I update my files and such, I just want to know if there's a way to know the actual state of the project tree and how to retrieve details from a specific change

any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Facebook and Subversion? Those kids aren't going to be pretty...

Comment: How about `svn log`, or the API equivalent?

Comment: +1 because I don't think it deserves to have -1... why was this downvoted anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2006/09/02/RSS-Subversion-Change-Log-.aspx) is advice on generating an RSS feed from Subversion.

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/rss_facebook_app_php) are instructions for making a Facebook app that reads an RSS feed.

I expect this in QA by EOB :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get away from ready-made RSS, you would be working with the `log` and `diff` subcommands/operations. You would ask for the log of commits since the last time you asked, and then get diffs for each change that you're interested in from that list retrieved.